# How to add a touch handler for a UIIMageView that is within two UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I created a custom navigation titleview by Creating a UIView called TitleView, then within that I store a UIView called containerView and within that It holds a UIImageView called profileImageView and a UILabel. I want to enable a touch handler on the UIImageView. So I tried adding it like so:

```
        //add touch handler to Profile Image to segue to expanded view
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(expandProfile))
        profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

and the touch handler as of now just prints - but it is never called

```
    //action for user clicking on the profile image view
    @objc func expandProfile() {
        print("THIS WORKS!!!")
    }
```

I am unsure why this isn't working. To try and fix this I enabled UserInteraction in the navigationbar the TitleView and the Container View but that didn't fix it? I am unsure what is causing the issue

edit to see the code that sets up my navigation bar:

```
    //Setting Up nav bar to have image and name
    func setupNavBar(){
        //We first create a titleview which we will use as the custom titleview in the navigation bar
        let titleView  = UIView()
        titleView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 60)
        //ContainerView will be within the titleview so that it allows it to grow dynamically with size of the name
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titleView.addSubview(containerView)
        //The view for storing the Profile picture of the match
        let profileImageView = UIImageView()
        profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: matchImageURLs[0])
        profileImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        profileImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        //Constraints for Profile Image
        profileImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        //add touch handler to Profile Image to segue to expanded view
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(expandProfile))
        profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(profileImageView)
        //View for the name of the match
        let nameLabel = UILabel()
        containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.text = matchName
        nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //Name Label constraints
        nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

        containerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        containerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true


        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
        //Adding the side menu button
        let elipsesImage = UIImage(systemName: "ellipsis")

        let menuItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: elipsesImage, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuTapped))
        menuItem.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 238/255, green: 119/255, blue: 98/255, alpha: 1)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuItem
        rightBarDropDown.anchorView = menuItem
        rightBarDropDown.dataSource = ["Un-Match","Block", "View Profile"]
        rightBarDropDown.cellConfiguration = { (index, item) in return "\(item)" }

    }
```

Comment: I try your code and it'' work fine. Maybe you can share all your codes?

Comment: I added my code for the functions that setup my navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

One or more of the views that you add the profile image to could have user interactions set to false. I suggest you set the tap gesture to be on containerView rather than on the profile image itself.

Comment: Even when I add it to the containerview it doesn't work, it only works when I add it to the navigation bar itself. And you can see in my function I set the user interactions true on all the different views which makes me confused on why it doesn't work.